# Bootstrap - Keeping buttons and search box aligned

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, search, button, navigation

I've searched and can't find a problem similar to mine, where it's partially responsive.  I have a footer with 3 buttons and a search box.  I'd like for them to be aligned and spaced evenly apart, which I've got figured out.  When I reduce the screen size, the buttons are responsive and stack correctly.  But the search box is aligning to the left instead of centering with the buttons.  Can anyone help?  I had to define a width for the search box in order to keep it cosmetically similar to the buttons.  I think maybe that's the problem?  Please help!  Here's my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/kEtr9/.

```
    <footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row navbar-inverse navbar-justified navbar-fixed-bottom row-fluid">
            <!-- replaced this with above: <div class="row"> -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"><!-- centers buttons when screen -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm fixed_button"><i class="icon-bolt"></i> submit bugs</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm fixed_button"><i class="icon-bolt"></i>Feature Requests</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm fixed_button"><i class="icon-bolt"></i>Contact</button></li>
                    <li>                
                        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 160px" class="form-control input-sm search-query" placeholder="Search">                       
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs" tabindex="-1">Go!</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :-)

`<input type="text" style="width: 160px; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="form-control input-sm search-query" placeholder="Search">`